# Check if dictionary value is empty in html template in Django/python notation

Tags: python, html, django

I am sending a context dictionary to an html page but I don't know how to perform an if statement on a specific value in the dictionary. This is what I'm doing.

In views where I'm calling a view method I am returning:

```
return render(request, 'shop/register.html', {'errors': errors, 'data': data})
```

where `errors` and `data` are also dictionaries themselves.

So in the html template how can I access one of the values in the `errors` field?

I tried doing this but it's not working:

```
{% if errors.username_error %} //should check if that value is not blank
    <h3>{{errors.username_error}}</h3>  //display error message
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What is rendered on the page if you just do `{{ data }}` or `{{ errors }}`?

Comment: @AndreyShipilov If i do `{{errors.username_error}}` it shows but it doesn't work in the if statement using the `{% %}` notation

Comment: That's not what I asked :)

Comment: @AndreyShipilov I tried `{{errors}}` and `{{data}}`and it does display correctly but the entire dictionaries, which I don't want

Comment: So it does show something like `{'username_error': 'The error.'}`?

Comment: @AndreyShipilov yeah exactly.

Comment: Well that's weird. What does this render? `{{ errors.username_error|yesno:"1,2" }}`

Comment: @AndreyShipilov A "1" with an error and "2" with no error

Comment: Hm. This is exceptionally weird then... I gotta say I don't know then. `{% if %}` on that should work fine man.

Comment: @AndreyShipilov I don't know what I was doing but I erased the code and redid it and now it works! I'm thinking I had some typo in there somewhere that I overlooked or something. I really appreciate the help man!

Comment: No worries mate.  :)

Comment: Use {% for %} and then if statement.

Answer (score 2):

So, the best way I know of to do this would be to include it as part of a [`for … empty`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#s-for-empty) statement, like so:

```
{% for error in errors %}
  <h3>{{error.username_error}}</h3>  {# display error message #}
{% empty %}  {# Triggered when the value in the dictionary is blank #}
  <h3>There is no error message to display</h3>
{% endfor %}
```